# Custom VSTO Context Menu - Active Inspector

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am attempting to add a Context Menu item in Outlook that adds a custom reply to a message, sends and deletes the original item.

```
<contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
      <menu id="OutlookPushContextMenu" label="EBS Plugins" getImage="imageLogo_GetImage" insertBeforeMso="Copy">
        <button id="OutlookPushEmail" label="Autograph Request" getImage="imageEmail_GetImage" onAction="AutographRequest_Click"/>
      </menu>
    </contextMenu>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMultipleItems">
      <menu id="OutlookPushContextMenu2" label="EBS Plugins" getImage="imageLogo_GetImage" insertBeforeMso="Copy">
        <button id="OutlookPushEmail2" label="Autograph Request" getImage="imageEmail_GetImage" onAction="AutographRequest_Click"/>
      </menu>
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>
```

```
      public void AutographRequest_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            Outlook.Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            Outlook.MailItem response = mailItem.ReplyAll();

            response.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            response.HTMLBody = "<p>Text</p> " + response.HTMLBody;
            response.Send();
            mailItem.Delete();

        }
```

When I right-click and select the Context Menu item I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

The ribbon item works without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assuming there is always an active inspector. Are you sure that's the case?
I'd imagine you mean to work with the currently selected message in an Explorer:

```
public void AutographRequest_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            Outlook.Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
            if (explorer != null)
            {
                Outlook.Selection selection = explorer.Selection;
                if (selection.Count >= 1)
                {  
                    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = selection[1] as Outlook.MailItem;
                    if (mailItem != null) //could be something other than MailItem
                    {
                        Outlook.MailItem response = mailItem.ReplyAll();

                        response.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
                        response.HTMLBody = "<p>Text</p> " + response.HTMLBody;
                        response.Send();
                        mailItem.Delete();
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```